# Getting compile time error while using lambda in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to use `FirstOrDefault` in my code but getting compile time error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type `Priority` to `bool`

```
    public class Priority
    {       
        public string Name { get; set; }      
        public string Id { get; set; }  
        public string Default { get; set; }           
    }
    
    public class ProcedureStatus
    {        
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Priorities Priorities { get; set; }
    }
    public class Priorities
    {       
        public List<Priority> Priority { get; set; }
    }

    foreach (Priority priority in status.Priorities.Priority)
    {
     if (priority.Default == "true" && grid.Priority == null)
     {
       grid.Priority = priority.Id;
       grid.PriorityText = priority.Name; 
       SetPriority(gridRow);                                 
        break;
     }
     else if (status.Priorities.Priority.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == priority.Id)) 
               priority.Default = "true";                                                 
                               
    }
```

How to use `FirstOrDefault` in my scenario.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` does return an element or null. If you want to check if there is an element matching that criteria you could use other methods like `Any`

Comment: @Cleptus, can you please show me an answer.

Comment: An answer would totally depend on what do you want inside your `else if` statement. Your problem is that whatever is that you are using a function that returns either `Priority` or `null`. None of those are a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `status.Priorities.Priority.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == priority.Id)` in an `if` clause.

The `if` clause is expecting an expression that returns a `bool`, but your expression returns a `Priority`.

Aside from that, it looks like the `if` clause is redundant, since you are iterating the properties via a `foreach` and trying to get the current item from the list you are already iterating. If you just want to iterate the list, you don't need the `if` clause.

The way you would typically use `FirstOrDefault` would be like this:

```
var priority = status.Priorities.Priority.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == priorityId)`;
if (priority != null)
{
  \\ ...
}
```

where `priorityId` is the ID of the priority you are looking for.

This does not seem useful inside you `foreach` loop though.

(Even after your question update, you still have the same `if` clause inside the `foreach`. It's just after an `if`/`else` now.)

Comment: Hi @Ergwun, Just updated my full code in `foreach` block. Please suggest answer.

Comment: You've still got the same issue after your update. What are you trying to achieve with the `if` clause?

Comment: Please see the if block. If that condition doesn't match then it should go to `else if` block where I am trying to find `priority.Id` in list `status.Priorities.Priority`. Once it finds then it should set the `priority.Default = "true"`.  It should only iterate in `else if` unless it finds the `priority.Id`.  Please suggest me an answer based on requirement. Thank you

Comment: You already have the instance of `Priority` with the matching ID. It is the one that `priority` refers to. You can just set it's default property directly. I don't think your algorithm makes much sense though. You iterate over the priorities, and foreach one, if it is not the default one, you set it to be the default one, then carry on iterating.

Comment: Can you please show me solution?

Answer (score 1):

## The problem

The problem is not related to Lambda expressions (`x => blablabla` syntax) but related to what a specific function [FirstOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-7.0) returns and how to use it in an if-else-elseif scenario.

## Analysis

The code you wrote could be written in two steps as:

```cs
if (priority.Default == "true" && grid.Priority == null)
{
    // your if block
} 
else 
{
    Priority firstPriority = status.Priorities.Priority.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == priority.Id);
    // Same exact error you got... Cannot implicitly convert type Priority to bool
    if (firstPriority) {
        priority.Default = "true";
    }
}
```

Now it is more easy to understand what the problem is... `if`, `else` and `else if` statements need a logical expression to work. That can be made either using a `bool` variable or doing a check/evaluation that returns `true`/`false`.

## Solution

There are many different ways to address the problem:

- You could use a function that directly returns a boolean like [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0), that would be useful if you do not need to use the object matching the `x => x.Id == priority.Id`.
- You could use `FirstOrDefault()` but changing your `else if` to convert it into something that return a logic expression. This would be useful if you need to later work with that element.

### Using the Any() function

```cs
else if (status.Priorities.Priority.Any(x => x.Id == priority.Id))
{
    priority.Default = "true"; // Dumb question, why the Default property is not of type bool???
}
```

### Using the FirstOrDefault()

Note: you have already been given this option in other answers. [Ergwun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75025263/2265446) and [Braulio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75025311/2265446) so far.

As per the documentation of the function I linked and what its name suggests, if the `FirstOrDefault()` function does not find anything, it returns `null`. So you could check it whatever it returns is null or not.

This could be done in a couple of ways. Depending on if you need to later work with whatever the function returns or not.

```cs
else if (status.Priorities.Priority.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == priority.Id) != null)
{
    priority.Default = "true";
}
```

or

```cs
if (priority.Default == "true" && grid.Priority == null)
{
    // your if block
} 
else 
{
    Priority firstPriority = status.Priorities.Priority.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == priority.Id);
    if (firstPriority != null) {
        priority.Default = "true";
        Console.WriteLine("The description of the priority if the Id XXXX is: " + firstPriority.Description);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way it's to compare if your object is not null after the research

```
 foreach (Priority priority in status.Priorities.Priority)
{
 if (grid.Priority == null)
 {
   grid.Priority = priority.Id;
   grid.PriorityText = priority.Name;                                  
    break;
 }
 else if (status.Priorities.Priority.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == priority.Id) != null) 
           // You found something, do this.                                                  
                           
}
```

Try it

Comment: Hi @Braulio Monroy, Just updated my full code in `foreach` block. Please suggest answer.